# Python - Passing a list from one function to another

Tags: python, list, function

Trying to pass a list from one function to another (teamurls), which then in turn I will use in another program. I have my program working where I have a value output using yield. (yield full_team_urls)
How do I pass the list from the first function into the second (the def - team_urls) Also is that still possible to return the list and continue using yield aswell?
Can each function only return or output one object?

Edit: Tried to pass teamurls into the second function as shown below and I get the error - TypeError: team_urls() missing 1 required positional argument: 'teamurls'>

```
def table():
    url = 'https://www.skysports.com/premier-league-table'

    base_url = 'https://www.skysports.com'

    today = str(date.today())

    premier_r = requests.get(url)

    print(premier_r.status_code)

    premier_soup = BeautifulSoup(premier_r.text, 'html.parser')

    headers = "Position, Team, Pl, W, D, L, F, A, GD, Pts\n"

    premier_soup_tr = premier_soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'standing-table__row'})

    premier_soup_th = premier_soup.find_all('thead')

    f = open('premier_league_table.csv', 'w')
    f.write("Table as of {}\n".format (today))
    f.write(headers)
    premier_soup_tr = premier_soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'standing-table__row'})
    result = [[r.text.strip() for r in td.find_all('td', {'class': 'standing-table__cell'})][:-1] for td in premier_soup_tr[1:]]
    teamurls = ([a.find("a",href=True)["href"] for a in premier_soup_tr[1:]])
    return teamurls
    for item in result:

        f.write(",".join(item))
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()


    print('\n Premier league teams full urls:\n')
    for item in teamurls:

        entire_team = []

#        full_team_urls.append(base_url+ item)
        full_team_urls = (base_url + item + '-squad')
        yield full_team_urls

table()

def team_urls(teamurls):
    teams = [i.strip('/') for i in teamurls]
    print (teams)
team_urls()
```

Comment: One object can contain many objects.. regardless, questions with (correct) formatting generally fair better.

Comment: Where is your _first_ function defined?

Comment: Is the code at the top (before def team_urls()) a method?

Comment: `yield` needs to be inside a function.

Comment: A function that uses `yields` should normally be called using an iteration statement, e.g. `for team_url in table():`

Comment: I iterate over what yields returns in another program in another file, if that matters?

Comment: May I kindly suggest that you do the official Python tutorial ? Getting values from functions and passing arguments to functions are really programming 101 question...

Answer (score 0):

To pass a value into a method, use arguments:

```
team_urls(teamurls)
```

You'll need to specify that argument at the definition of `team_urls` as such:

```
def team_urls(teamurls):
```

Comment: yea i tried that and got TypeError: team_urls() missing 1 required positional argument: 'teamurls'

Comment: @anfield I assumed you understood basic conventions of Python. Check the edit.

Comment: @anfield you still need to put a value in the function call in order for that value to be passed into the function!